# corrupted aspx and cs file shown as aspx.cs.lokf i'm using vs2015

Tags: c#

My project files does not show in original form (e.g Default.aspx or Default.cs) now it shown Default.aspx.lokf and Default.aspx.cs.lokf. Please help me if you have any idea or best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a ransomware.

Take a look at this article [here](https://adware.guru/lokf-ransomware-decrypt-files/). Did you see a  readme file in the folder that gives you directions?

Based on another article/guide [here](https://www.myantispyware.com/2019/11/08/lokf-file-extension-remove-lokf-virus-restore-decrypt-lokf-files/), it might even be impossible to recover the encrypted files if the key is online.

To say the least, you need to remove the ransomware As Soon As Possible to avoid infecting other files.